Poynting vector, photon population and instantaneous field strength
If I have two sinusoidal waves $E_1(x,t)$ and $E_2(x,t)$ superimposing to form $E(x,t)$, and I measure the photons passing through some $dS$ at some $x_0$ throughout some $dt$, and I get a tally of $N_1$ photons with frequency $\nu_1$ and $N_2$ photons with frequency $\nu_2$, then the Poynting vector $S=\frac{1}{\mu_0}E\times B\propto E^2$ suggests that I cannot simply take the total instantaneous photon energy transport power to be $(N_1h\nu_1+N_2h\nu_2)/dt$ since $(E_1+E_2)^2\neq E_1^2+E_2^2$, right? I have to take the phase information of the two variants of photons into consideration.

Such EM field has a distribution of phases with low spread, and can be described in QT by coherent states. Such have number of photons uncertain, with a distribution that has an average but also large spread. Even if you measure some numbers $N_1,N_2$ somehow, these will be to a large extent random, and will change from trial to trial. Averages can probably be related to net electric field amplitude square in the way you suggest, after proper reinterpretation of $N_1,N_2$.But your argument is not very convincing, because there is no obvious requirement that $N_1$ is in fixed relation to $E_1$.

@Ján Lalinský I'm trying to find if there's a way to add photons as classical particles to the classical EM field worldview. The photons here are classical particles with zero volume and definite trajectory

Why? What effect would such particles have on predictions of classical theory?

Consider the electric fields of two plane sinusoidal electromagnetic waves propagating in  x-direction $$E_1=E_{10}\cos(k_1 x-\omega_1 t) \tag 1$$ $$E_2=E_{20}\cos(k_2 x-\omega_2 t+ \delta) \tag 2$$ In plane waves the corresponding perpendicular B vectors are given by $B=E/c$. Then the energy flux densities of these waves are the Poynting vectors $$S_1=\frac{1}{\mu_0}E_1 \times B_1 = c\epsilon_0E_1^2 \tag 3$$ and $$S_2=\frac{1}{\mu_0}E_2 \times B_2 = c\epsilon_0E_2^2 \tag 4$$ The energy flux density of the superimposed waves $E=E_1+E_2$ is given by the Poynting vector $$S=\frac{1}{\mu_0}E\times B=c\epsilon_0(E_1+E_2)^2=c\epsilon_0 (E_1^2+2E_1E_2+E_2^2) \tag5$$ The term $2E_1E_2$ in the bracket shows that the energy flux density of the superimposed wave (5) is not just the sum of the energy flux densities (3) and (4).
One should keep in mind that these Poynting vectors correspond to instantaneous energy flux densities, i.e.,to variable energy densities that move with light velocity $c$ according to the sinusoidal wave functions of the electric fields (1) and (2).
The simplest semiclassical way to consider this as flux densities of photons is to divide these energy flux densities, i.e., the energy densities times $c$, by the respective photon energies $\hbar \omega$. However, you cannot simply split the instant energy flux density (5) into two instant photon flux densities $S_1/(\hbar \omega_1)$ and $S_2/(\hbar \omega_2)$ corresponding to (3) and (4) with frequencies $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ due to the $2E_1(\omega_1) E_2(\omega_2)$ term.
This problem can be resolved by considering the mean energy flux of the superimposed wave over many (ideally infinite) cycles of the respective waves. Then you can show that the mean cross-term $<2E_1(\omega_1) E_2(\omega_2)>$ becomes negligible for a large number of cycles as compared to the mean quadratic $<E_1^2>$ and $<E_2^2>$ terms due to its (double) sinusoidal oscillatory behavior.
Thus the mean photon flux density of the superimposed wave becomes the sum of the mean photon flux densities of the constituent waves.

also note that Fourier transformation is non-causal, i.e. it's impossible to say how many photons of a particular frequency there should be unless one has the entire signal, not ending just at the current moment, if photons are really classical particles.

You have to distinguish between how you generate the EM waves and how you measure them.
Generating EM waves

Take a photon beam and pass it through a circular hole with a rotating semicircle as an aperture. You get a sinusoidal intensity distribution over time. However, photons are not polarized; their two field components E and B are perpendicular to each other and perpendicular to the direction of movement of the photon, but are equally distributed over 360°.
A not entirely unimportant side note: Your photons have the frequencies of your thermal source (wide frequency range) or, for example, a monochromatic source (e.g. a sodium vapor lamp); the frequency of the wave, on the other hand, is determined by the rotational frequency of the semicircular aperture.

Move surface electrons back and forth in a conductor. The electrons will emit photons during their acceleration phases. Depending on the voltage applied and the frequency of the wave generator, the frequency of the individual photons will range from IR to X-rays. In total, you will obtain a temporally sinusoidal intensity distribution in which the emitted photons are polarized - the E-field component parallel to the direction of acceleration of the electrons on the antenna rod, the B-field component perpendicular to it.
You will take care of the not entirely unimportant side note by yourself.


Measuring the characteristics of an EM wave

If you use no other tool than a bolometer, you will find that two waves add up for both of the methods of generating EM waves described above. A bolometer simply measures the number of incident photons (as a temperature curve). Of course, this only applies exactly to waves of monochromatic photons, but physics deals with models, and we want to look at such a simple one here.
TL;DR
There is no subtraction or extinction or destructive interference because an EM wave can only have an intensity between zero and maximum. This is in complete contrast to a mechanical wave, where the kinetic energy between the zero crossings must be considered as + and -.
TL;DR

An EM wave can be characterized by more than just its intensity. When a photon strikes a body, the E-field component interacts with the surface electrons. For example, total internal reflection occurs on glass or water. If two waves from thermal sources hit a conductor and we use electrical measurements to investigate the superposition of the waves, we fail. The measurement result of the bolometer - or the thermal heating plus the reflected radiation - are the only statements we can make.
.
The situation is different with two radio waves - i.e. the example two from above. The periodically changing orientation of the E-field component of the photons involved plays a key role here:
_ When a radio wave strikes a receiver conductor, the concerted effect of the polarized photons sets surface electrons on the conductor in motion - in other words, the reversal process of the transmitter rod.
_ If two EM waves now hit the receiver rod, both will influence the electrons in competition. This affects both the polarization directions of the two waves - two crossed polarizations are no problem for the radio technician - as well as the periodicity of the two waves.  Two radio waves with the same carrier frequency and opposite periodicity of their E-field components cancel each other out perfectly. The surface electrons remain where they are.



Meatball Princess: I have to take the phase information of the two variants of photons into consideration?

Yes.
